# How to find SQL Connection String when VS is not installed on the same server as SQL is

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio is installed on my computer. I am doing RDP to a network computer on which SQL Server is installed. I need to put in the connection string as per the network computer on which I have the required database.
I know how to pick connection string when doing it within the visual studio, but here I need to retrieve it only via SQL Server and then copy paste it to VS.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magiс in SQL server connection string and you can construct it manually using server name and some options.

When you're connecting using username and password it basically looks like

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

When you're using trusted connection (windows authentication) it looks like

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Have a look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more details and options concerning SQL server connection strings